# Google Scripts - Add todays date in specific cell, but ignore updating cell again if overtyped

Tags: google-sheets

So I'm trying to accomplish the following.

Whenever I enter something into Column A... today's date goes into Column O (of the same row). I have this code already, however I need to modify it slightly.

```
  function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var col        = activeCell.getColumn();
  var row        = activeCell.getRow();


// If the Reference is put into Column A, then todays date is automatically put into Column O

  if (col == 1 && sheet.getRange(row, col) != "") { // 1 = Column A
      sheet.getRange(row, col+14).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+00:00", "''dd-MM-yyyy")); // +14 = Column O
  }

}
```

So this does what I need it to do.
But the modifications that I want to accomplish are:

If the value in Column A is updated for whatever reason (tomorrow for example), then the date in column O will also be updated. I don't want this to happen. I want the date to remain as it is.

Is this possible?

I might as well ask my other question that I've been pondering on.

I don't really like the whole "col == 1" for column A, and "col+14" for Column O.
Is there a way that I can search for column headings? and dynamically use that instead.

Column A heading is: Reference Number

Column O heading is: Date Received

I'm familiar with Excel VBA, and I know that you can do this type of thing in that language, but I don't know how to do it in Google Scripts.

Any help with this will be most appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure you dont overwrite the value. You just have to modify the if statement to check if the value of the cell is empty like so

```
if (col == 1 &&                                    // check if the column no is 1
  sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue() != "" &&     // Check if the new edited value is not empty
  sheet.getRange(row, col + 14).getValue() == "") {  // check if col 14 is empty
  sheet.getRange(row, col + 14).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+00:00", "''dd-MM-yyyy")); // +14 = Column O
}
```

To get the column number based on specific strings in headers, first get values in the first row. Then use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=example) function to determine which array element has that particular string, (add 1 to it, since array index starts at 0, spreadsheet col number start at 1)

```
var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]   //Get the first row values in a 2D array, then get the first row (0)

  //find the columns with following headers
  var headerFind = ["Reference Number","Date Received"]
  // column numbers with the given headers
  var col1 = headers.indexOf(headerFind[0]) + 1
  var col2 = headers.indexOf(headerFind[1]) + 1
  Logger.log(col1)
  Logger.log(col2)
```

Final code would like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var col        = activeCell.getColumn();
  var row        = activeCell.getRow();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]   //Get the first row values in a 2D array, then get the first row (0)

  //find the columns with following headers
  var headerFind = ["Reference Number","Date Received"]
  // column numbers with the given headers
  var col1 = headers.indexOf(headerFind[0]) + 1
  var col2 = headers.indexOf(headerFind[1]) + 1
  Logger.log(col1)
  Logger.log(col2)

// If the Reference is put into Column A, then todays date is automatically put into Column O

  if (col == col1 &&                                    // check if the column no is 1
      sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue() != "" &&     // Check if the new edited value is not empty
      sheet.getRange(row, col2).getValue() == "") {  // check if col2 is empty
      sheet.getRange(row, col2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+00:00", "''dd-MM-yyyy")); // +14 = Column O
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Wow, getting the column headers is certainly more involved than VBA, but nonetheless it works perfectly. I'll also be able to use this logic in some of my other projects so thank you for your lengthy reply!!